# Zend setData method prevents Collection::setCount working

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form, zend-framework3, zend-form-element

I have a Zend_Form with a Collection of Select elements. I want to increase the number of elements in that collection whilst also preserving any selection made previously (previous selections are stored in a POST request).

I use `$form->setData($data);` to save the values in the POST request to the Zend_Form.

I then use  `$form->get('countryTest')->setCount(9);` to try and increase the number of Selection elements in the Collection. However, `setCount()` doesn't seem to change the count when used in combination with `setData()`. Any idea why? What should I do instead?

My Collection:

```
$this->add(array(
            'name' => 'countryTest',
            'type' => 'Collection',
            'options' => array(
                'label' => '',
                'count' => 3,
                'should_create_template' => true,
                'target_element' => array(
                    'type' => 'Select',
                    'options' => array(
                        'label' => 'Country',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ));
```

**EDIT:**

I've also tried constructing a new Zend_Form with a larger number of elements in the Collection and THEN using `setData()` but doing this seems to reduce the number of elements in the Collection to the number of elements in the data (probably as expected).

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution:

Make the number of elements I want present in the array (in the form of keys) that I pass into `setData()`.